# Node.js - Route gets choked in a long running task

Tags: node.js, express, es6-promise

A miniature express app that pings `google.com` and dumps the result in the browser. 
Since, ping takes some time, say 3 seconds so until those 3 seconds have past and the ping results are available, the route gets chocked/blocked and all requests come to a stand still awaiting the ping to finish.
I'm using `promises` and the `child_process.exec` which is asynchronous as well.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const {exec} = require('child_process');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    let receivedAt = new Date();

    if (new Date() % 5 === 0 || new Date() % 2 === 0) {
        res.status(200).send(
            `<pre>OK
                <em>
                <br>Received at &#8594;  ${receivedAt} 
                <br>Responded at &#8594;  ${new Date()}
                </em>
            </pre>`);
    } else {
        let pingPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            exec('ping google.com', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                if (error) {
                    reject(stderr);
                }
                resolve(stdout);
            });
        });
        pingPromise.then((data) => {
            res.status(200).send(
                `<pre>${data}
                    <em>
                    <br>Received at &#8594;  ${receivedAt} 
                    <br>Responded at &#8594;  ${new Date()}
                    </em>
                </pre>`);
        });
    }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('App is listening on port 3000!')
});
```

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: @YouneL → Windows

Comment: i don't see where you spawn or close child process, but if you are spawning/killing child processes regularly, it maybe what is "choking" your node js instance, i also don't see why you would use both child processes and async execution, i personally am used to seeing either one or the other implemented